# Create a TXT record for Bonjour NetService in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour

I am creating an application for Peer-to-Peer Chatting using [Apple's Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002445-SW1) in Swift 3.

After publishing a NetService I want to add a user_id and name parameters as TXT record. I have spent 3 - 4 hours on searching how to create a TXT record in Swift 3, but didn't find any useful solution. Once I set TXT record for a NetService, I also want to read it

For setting the TXT record data we have to use 
[func setTXTRecord(Data?)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/netservice/1410648-settxtrecord)

Please suggest me how I can Set and Get TXT record of a NetService

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. These are NetServiceDelegate calls.

```
public func netServiceDidPublish(_ service: NetService) {
    let txtDict = ["peerID": _localNode.peerID.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!]
    let txtData = NetService.data(fromTXTRecord: txtDict)
    if !service.setTXTRecord(txtData) {
        print("did not set txtRecord")
    }
}

public func netService(_ service: NetService, didUpdateTXTRecord data: Data) {
    let txtDict = NetService.dictionary(fromTXTRecord: data)
    if let idObject = txtDict["peerID"], let peerID = NSString(data: idObject, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {
        // use peerID
    }
}
```

If you like, you can see this in action from my project on GitHub: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ALBPeerConnection.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I have another problem with this, When my app goes in background then it calls didRemove netService and the device becomes undiscoverable. Can you suggest some solution to discover device when it is in background?

Comment: When an app goes to the background on iOS, network connections are lost. You can request a little time to finish a task, but it isn't guaranteed. Bottom line: Don't expect networking from a backgrounded app.

Comment: Is there any way to determine that the another user's app is running in background or terminated?

Comment: @RajatJain There is not.